# Eclipse resulting different output while debug and run

Tags: java

```
//Here is my code, My intention is to print the time in 24 Hour format
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Solution {
    static String timeConversion(String s) {
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ":");
        String hrs = st.nextToken();
        String mins = st.nextToken();
        String secs = st.nextToken();

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(hrs));
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(mins));
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(secs.substring(0, 2)));
        if (secs.substring(2).equalsIgnoreCase("AM")) {
            c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        }
        if (secs.substring(2).equalsIgnoreCase("PM")) {
            c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        }

        return c.getTime().toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("12:00:00AM: " + timeConversion("12:00:00AM"));// 00:00:00
        System.out.println("12:00:00PM: " + timeConversion("12:00:00PM"));// 12:00:00
        System.out.println("07:05:45PM: " + timeConversion("07:05:45PM"));// 07:05:45PM

    }
}
```

### Output

### Debug

12:00:00AM: Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2

12:00:00PM: Wed Dec 31 12:00:00 IST 2

07:05:45PM: Wed Dec 31 19:05:45 IST 2

---

### Compile (Ctrl + F11)

12:00:00AM: Wed Dec 31 12:00:00 IST 2

12:00:00PM: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1

07:05:45PM: Wed Dec 31 19:05:45 IST 2

Comment: I tried your code in IntelliJ IDEA, run and debug gives same results. You may check your vm arguments, debug may have a different timezone. Or you may try in another IDE.

Comment: I tried this in Eclipse (2018-12) and JDK 11, it gives the same results as in your "Compile" in both "Run as"/ "Debug as" Java Application . The second date is Jan 01.

Answer (score 0):

For avoid problems with differents timezones you can set it in the code with:

```
TimeZone.setDefault( TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1") );
```

as first sentence of your main method.

This solution works for me running the rest of your code with Java 8

Comment: Were you able to reproduce getting different results running in debug and non-debug?

Comment: No really because im sure im using the same JVM and parameteres for run and debug